# Angular Directive for keydown breaks other functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to listen to keydown events on a formfield. To do this I've built a directive with a "keydown" attribute as follows:

```
var keydown = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            keydown: '=keydown'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            $(elem).keydown(function(evt){
                scope.keydown(evt);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Now I add this to my inputs markup:

```
<input class="search-input" type="text" ng-model="queryStr" ng-change="redrawUI()" keydown="processSearchBox" >
```

Now my keydown function is called and that works fine... however now my model is no longer bound to the input form field... if I change the model the form doesn't update

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are creating a new "isolate" scope which is detached from the scope where `redrawUI()` lives. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnunamak/Apy74/) for an alternate approach where you inherit from the parent scope and use `scope.$eval` to process your event.